# Function provided by flip.to doesn't work on my Next.js project

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have this script provided by flip.to

```
<script>
        !function(b,e){
        (b[e] = b[e] || []).push({
          flipto: {
            bookingEngine: "Demo",
            companyCode: "XX",
            code: "YYYY",
          },
        })
      }(window,'fliptoDataLayer');
</script>
```

If i add this code to a next page/component, there's a JavaScript error: "b and e are undefined"

How can i rewrite this function in order to work on next.js project? Thanks

This is how error looks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          <script
            type="text/javascript"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `!function(b,e){
                (b[e] = b[e] || []).push({
                 flipto: {
                  bookingEngine: "Demo",
                  companyCode: "XX",
                  code: "YYYY",
               },
             })
             }(window,'fliptoDataLayer');`,
            }}
          />
```